# Convert ORC file to Parquet file

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, parquet, orc

Are there any known libraries/approaches for converting ORC files to Parquet files? Otherwise I am thinking of using Spark to import an ORC into a dataframe then output into parquet file

Comment: Spark, Hive, Pig, MapReduce, NiFi. Yes, it can be done. What is wrong with the approach you have thought of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned using Spark for reading ORC files, creating DataFrames and then storing those DFs as Parquet Files. This is a perfectly valid and quite efficient approach!

Also depending on your preference, also your use case, you can use even Hive or Pig[may be you can throw-in Tez for a better performance here] or Java MapReduce or even NiFi/StreamSets [depending on your distribution]. This is a very straightforward implementation and you can do it whatever suits you best [or whatever you are most comfortable with :)]

Comment: ./spark-shell
val orcfile = "hdfs:///mypath/*.orc*"
val df = spark.read.format("orc").load(orcfile)
df.printSchema()
df.count()
df.createOrReplaceTempView("MYTBL")
val results = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM MYTBL")
spark.sql("desc formatted MYTBL").show()
results.count()
results.write.mode("Overwrite").format("parquet").save("hdfs:///mypath/mytbl") 
hls -R /mypath/mytbl/
#my parquet files!

Answer (score 1):

One Way of doing this is :

Step 1) First you need to create a table from ORC table with "Stored As Text"
Step 2) Secondly you can create A table from previous output as "Stored As Parquet"
Step 3) After that you can drop intermediate table.